# SQL to compare date in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, date-comparison

I need to compare the user input date `kakko` (yyyy-mm-dd format) with the CreateDate and UpdateDate in table productinfo and return the result.

This does not work.

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `productinfo` WHERE CreateDate > %s-%s-%s AND CreateDate <= (SELECT MAX( UpdateDate ) FROM productinfo) AND Updatedate = (SELECT MAX( UpdateDate ) FROM productinfo) ",kakko)
db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
sql ='SELECT 
    *
    FROM
        productinfo
    WHERE
        CreateDate > ? AND CreateDate <= (SELECT 
                MAX(UpdateDate)
            FROM
                productinfo) AND Updatedate = (SELECT 
                MAX(UpdateDate)
            FROM
                productinfo)';
cur.execute(sql,kakko)
db.commit
```

Comment: thanks, but errors is: not enough arguments for format string

Answer (score 0):

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `productinfo` WHERE CreateDate > '%s'" %(kakko,))
result = cur.fetchall()
```

works!